# What's the tag for washing before cooking? Please create one?

Tags: discussion, tagging

1. Users wrongly tagged the following [cleaning], because [cleaning] is intended

> [For questions about cleaning kitchen equipment after use. Please also tag with type of equipment you're cleaning. Do not use for food preparation (washing produce, cleaning fish, etc), just use the tag for the food you're preparing](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning)

[How do I clean kale and other leafy vegetables for cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1287)
[Can I safely clean/eat harvested foods that have aphids on them?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23573)
[Is it normal to wash an apple, or other fruits, with dish washing liquid?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/43038)
[How to clean food that may have been contaminated by a cockroach?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/116319)
[What is the point of washing produce in cold water?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/117206)
[When washing ingredients, does it matter if the water is cold or warm?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/117240)

2. What (new?) tag can envelop the following questions?

[How briny should the water be when soaking broccoli to remove bugs?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/2259)
[Red apples safety](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4251)
[Should dry beans be washed before soaking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6768)
[What should I know about the peels of raw fruit and vegetables?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18477)
[Basil - to wash or not to wash? Best practices?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/23794)
[How to wash vegetables without running water?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/24382)
[How do you wash fruit and veggies effectively?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/25217)
[does washing vegetables and fruit with baking soda make sense?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/34384)
[How do I properly wash bugs out of green onion?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/50391)
[is it okay to wash vegetables by soaking/submerging?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/54977)
[Is it safe to not wash mushrooms?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/55250)
[Do you have to wash frozen vegetables?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/58352)
[Appliance to wash or scrub fruit and vegetables? Washer or scrubber](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/75435)
[Can I simply soak fruit and vegetables in water for several hours to sanitize them?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/76376)
[Do you need to rinse vegetables that can be peeled?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/76590)
[How important is washing produce?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/90113)
[Super tiny bugs in store bought raspberries](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/92566)
[When to wash fruits and vegetables?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/108016)
[Peel first, wash first, or don't peel at all vegetables?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/112882)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, we should add the tag WASHING-FOOD (or a similar name) for this.  Mostly people seem to me using FOOD SAFETY, which is our most overused tag, making it not very helpful.

An alternative would be something like FOOD-PREPARATION, but that's probably too general to be useful.